# How i can doing for adquire a last entry in database with a field filter in django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-views

I need adquire last entry in my database but with a field user=XXXX

for example:

```
  def entry_database(token):
      dev = get_object_or_404(db_something, pk=token)
      configuration = get_object_or_404(bd_mytable, pk=dev.conf_id)
```

But I want that my 'configuration' = last entry with field user=XXXX

My models:

```
class db_something(models.Model):
      ...
    conf_id = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    user = models.CharField(max_length=15)
      ...
class bd_mytable(models.Model):
      ...
    user = models.CharField(max_length=15)
      ...
```

Comment: Show us your models.

Comment: only need this data from my models.
rest not affect to function, Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly... try this:

```
 def entry_database(token):
     dev = get_object_or_404(db_something, pk=token)
     configuration = bd_mytable.objects.filter(user=dev.user).last()
```